# запросы к firebird на WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Имею:

Есть сайт написанный на SimpleCMS. Логика сервера и все запросы к fb хранил в файлике query.php (их не много, всего в файлике порядка 1500 строк)к и были они характера:

```
// подключение к БД
$host = '*'; // адрес сервера
$database = '*// имя базы данных
$user = '*'; // имя пользователя
$password = '*'; // пароль

//.....
else if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == 'compareTokens')
{
    // тут могут быть запросы к БД
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $personalAccount = $_POST['personalAccount'];

    if ($token === $_SESSION["token"][$personalAccount]){
        echo json_encode(array('successed' => true));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('successed' => false, 'token' => $token, 'ses_token_arr' => $_SESSION["token"]));
    }
}
//.....
```

цель: Перенести и сделать магию, чтобы все заработало на `WP`.

Вопрос: может ли `WP` обрабатывать серверную логику `php` (я так понимаю, что `WP` грузится с под сервака, т. е. если я буду класть `php` фалы во внутрь него, то они должны выполнятся). Если это суждение не верно - то поправьте меня?

Сделал:

Попробовал создать файлик такой-же в темах `wp`, порпобовал через get-запрос - отрабатывает. Но при попытске выполнения запроса на `firebird` коннект падает в `die` с ошибкой  `Unable to complete network request to host "". Failed to establish a connection.`

Читал про `$wpdb`, но мне бы обработать запросы нативным `php`. Возможно кто-то знает решение?

Comment: 1. Исправь вопрос, расшифровав "fb". 2 ВП не работает с firebird. 3. Для работы с базами в ВП - онли wbdb, никаких "нативных php".

Comment: @SeVlad даже если "очень костыльным" способом - то никак (я на счет обычных коннектов-запросов НЕ через оболочку wp)?

Comment: WP написан на обычном php. Любой php-файл в папке WordPress будет исполняться, как и вне WordPress, если вызван напрямую.